# FCrDNS for a mail server that also runs other services (http, ftp etc)

Tags: email, spf, reverse-dns, ptr-record, fcrdns

I am learning how to administer productive internet-facing machines and services, and towards that end setting up mail, web, and a couple other services, all on the *same box* (budget constraints and simplicity).

My question relates to: *SPF*, *FCrDNS*, and `PTR` records:

SPF clearly recommends *not* using its `PTR` mechanism any more. Given this, when setting up an SPF record with some other mechanism (e.g. the `MX` mechanism), does it *still* make sense to set up a `PTR` record that leads to *FCrDNS*? If so, how should this set-up look like?

Currently, my zone file looks something like:

```
# zone file for example.com
@        A        <ip>
www      A        <ip>
ftp      A        <ip>
mail     A        <ip>
@        MX       mail
@        TXT      "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Where `<ip>` value for all records. i.e. I run multiple services on the same machine.

Given this, how should I set up rDNS? like:

```
<ip>.in-addr.arpa    PTR    mail.example.com.
```

or like:

```
<ip>.in-addr.arpa    PTR    example.com.
```

The first option (i.e. have the `PTR` record point back to `mail.example.com`) doesn't seem to represent the actual situation to me. After all, `<ip>` doesn't exclusively deal with email. The second option sounds like a clearer representation of what `<ip>` is associated with (i.e. *all* services for `example.com`), but I'm not sure which is preferred by popular mail services when scoring email for spam, and why.

Comment: SPF and FCrDNS are completely unrelated, separate checks. You need to set up both, but they are not tied together in any way.

Comment: A PTR record is always a good idea, since some mail servers will not accept mails from ip-addresses that does not have a PTR record (or where the domain name from the PTR record does not resolve back to the same IP-address).